# from net471 to .NET Standard noob questions

Tags: vb.net, migration, .net-standard

I have a very old VB project I am looking to modernize to which I created a new solution (will convert code to C# later on), am re-adding the libraries and web projects to the new solution to eliminate the old project having old .publishproj, references to mscorlib 2.0 (despite best efforts to resolve through re-adding references) and several other issues that will likely go away.

In the process, I figured to try to go to .NET Standard for the standardized PCL that will allow for future use with Xamarin, Mono, etc.  I am not fully versed in .NET Standard so need some input (attempting 2.0 based on the scaling effect of 2.0 down from what I read)

The problems I am running into are:

1) I have several basic CORE functions from the .NET Framework that are not recognized in .NET Standard:

IsNumeric, IsNothing, IsDBNull, IIF

Any suggestions as to why this is?

(re-edit to remove Hold)
Thank you to jmcilhinney for answering :-)

Comment: ONE Pokemon per Poke Ball! ONE question per Stack Overflow question post!

Comment: Question #2 is itself off-topic.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

All four of `IsNumeric`, `IsNothing`, `IsDBNull` and `IIf` are VB-specific. They can't be part of .NET Standard if they've never been accessible to other languages without referencing the Microsoft.VisualBasic assembly.  You really shouldn't have been using any of them previously anyway as they are holdovers from VB6.

In the case of `IsNumeric`, it uses `Double.TryParse` internally anyway.  In fact, `Double.TryParse` was written specifically to improve the performance of `IsNumeric`.  You should be using the `TryParse` method of the appropriate numeric type yourself if you want to know whether a `String` can be converted to that type.

In the case of `IsNothing`, you should simply be comparing your reference to `Nothing`, e.g. instead of:

```
If IsNothing(myThing) Then
```

you should be using:

```
If myThing Is Nothing then
```

In the case of `IsDBNull`, you should be doing much as above, e.g. instead of:

```
If IsDBNull(myThing) Then
```

you should be using:

```
If myThing Is DBNull.Value Then
```

That said, both a `DataRow` and a data reader have their own dedicated methods to tell you whether one of their fields is NULL.

In the case of `IIf`, it always had it's issues because it is a method that people tried to treat like an operator in many cases.  I think it was VB 2008 that actually did introduce an `If` operator that works much like the C# ternary operator, so you should have been using that since then anyway, e.g. instead of:

```
myVar = IIf(someBooleanExpression, someValue, someOtherValue)
```

you should have been using:

```
myVar = If(someBooleanExpression, someValue, someOtherValue)
```

There are some subtle differences between `IIf` and `If` but I'll leave you to read about how `If` works for yourself.