# How to get the total of a column in DataGridView

Tags: vb.net

Every time there is a blank cell the result is 0?

```
Dim tot As Decimal
Try
    If BREAKDOWNLIST.RowCount <> 1 Then
        For Each row As DataGridViewRow In BREAKDOWNLIST.Rows
            If IsNothing(Me.BREAKDOWNLIST.CurrentRow.Cells(5).Value) Then

            Else
                If BREAKDOWNLIST.RowCount = 1 Then
                    tot = Val(row.Cells(5).Value)
                ElseIf BREAKDOWNLIST.RowCount > 1 Then
                    tot += Val(row.Cells(5).Value)
                End If
            End If
        Next
    ElseIf BREAKDOWNLIST.RowCount = 1 Then
    End If

    TOTAL.Text = tot
Catch
End Try
```

Comment: Are you sure the content of the cells is Integer and not String?

Comment: Is the grid bound to a `DataTable`? If so then an "empty" cell actually contains `DBNull.Value` rather than `Nothing`. If it is bound to a `DataTable` then you can simply call the `Compute` method of that `DataTable`.

Comment: You see where you have an empty `Catch`? That could be hiding errors which you need to see from you.

Answer (score 1):

Like Mat said but I like the .net way better. They say `TryParse` is faster which could make a difference if you have an awful lot of rows.

```
Dim decValue As Decimal
Dim tot As Decimal
For Each row As DataGridViewRow In BREAKDOWNLIST.Rows
    If Decimal.TryParse(row.Cells(5).Value, decValue) Then
        tot += decValue
    End If
Next
```

Comment: Did a short test and the method in my answer was about 10% faster than yours with `TryParse` (tested with 1M rows). Do you have a link/reference to the statement that `TryParse` is faster than `IsNumeric`?

Comment: An expanded quote "In the case of IsNumeric, it uses Double.TryParse internally anyway. In fact, Double.TryParse was written specifically to improve the performance of IsNumeric. You should be using the TryParse method of the appropriate numeric type yourself if you want to know whether a String can be converted to that type." by jmcilhinney on SO (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48046279/from-net471-to-net-standard-noob-questions)

Comment: My test came out a bit different. Each 1M, The dot NET loop took 232 milliseconds.
The VB6 loop took 312 milliseconds.
The dot NET loop took 231 milliseconds.
The VB6 loop took 419 milliseconds.
The dot NET loop took 249 milliseconds.
The VB6 loop took 342 milliseconds.
The dot NET loop took 234 milliseconds.
The VB6 loop took 322 milliseconds.

Comment: @MatSnow I ran my test from within the VS 2017 environment which is probably the wrong way to do it. I used the .Net Stopwatch class. I never tried to time anything before. Husband was disgusted with me that I hadn't. :-(

Comment: @Mary I have now determined why the results were different. I've made a double conversion inside the loop because of copy paste the wrong line from another test. Instead of `tot += decValue` i've pasted `tot += CDec(row.Cells(5).Value)`. So your results are correct. Sorry :) (BTW I've tested the same way with Stopwatch)

Answer (score 0):

If the cell contains no value, an [`InvalidCastException`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.invalidcastexception%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) is thrown and the `Try`-block is left.

So you'll need to check the cell for a numeric value before calculating.
Furthermore you can shorten your code and omit the `Try/Catch`-block:

```
Dim tot As Decimal

For Each row As DataGridViewRow In BREAKDOWNLIST.Rows
    If IsNumeric(row.Cells(5).Value) Then
        tot += Val(row.Cells(5).Value)
    End If
Next

TOTAL.Text = tot.ToString()
```