# how to text changed in DevExpress GridView Vb.net

Tags: vb.net, devexpress

Good day,

I have column in gridview named "Amount" and it's editable. I have also TotalAmountTextEdit that computes the total of Column "Amount". When I edit the value in Column "Amount". It wont recompute. I used this code. Please help me who can modify this code. Thank you.

```
Private Sub GridView1_CellValueChanged(sender As Object, e As Views.Base.CellValueChangedEventArgs) Handles GridView1.CellValueChanged
        TotalAmountTextEdit.Text = GridView1.Columns("Amount").SummaryItem.SummaryValue
    End Sub
```

Comment: why not use https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48275713/how-to-get-the-total-of-a-column-in-datagridview